Extremely slow iteration on Xbox Series S (UWP)
I'm encountering insane times when trying to iterate through nested for loops.
The original code instantiates up to 20k objects in Unity within three nested for loops, called during the Awake() stage.
This code takes a second on my desktop PC running 8 core Ryzen 7 2700X, which should provide similar performance as the Custom AMD Zen 2 with 8 cores on the Xbox Series S I'm deploying to. Only it doesn't.
The time it takes the Xbox to iterate through is whopping 15 minutes! When I remove one instantiation call, it drops down to 8 minutes, but even a dummy iteration of the same size that only prints out a debug message 10k times takes whole 6 seconds to iterate through.
Now I'm well aware instantiation in Unity is slow, but since the desktop can crunch two instantiations per 10k iterations within a second, I really don't understand why it takes 15 minutes on the Xbox.
Could someone please point me in the right direction as I have no idea what am I dealing with here.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that the VS profiler shows the CPU running at stable 15% load during the iteration process.

Instantiating 20k objects is a lot! you'd have to profile to find out why xbox takes so much longer. However, for that kinda problem and having that many objects i would assume moving (unless you're making minecraft type or such) that dots maybe more suitable.

I will do that as a workaround, unless I figure this out. Forgot to mention the profiler in VS shows the CPU running at stable 15% load while iterating through the loops. But like I mentioned, the desktop can handle the loop with two instantiations in a matter of a second.

Pretty sure Xbox stats arent as many cores, memory, graphics card capabilities ..

I suppose there is something wrong in your objects Awake/Start/OnEnable? Maybe you search for some resources etc.? The reason why "empty" loop takes 6 seconds is because its not empty and Debug.Log is quite expensive, check the time without log

@PawełŁęgowski Thank you for your input. But can you explain how this could be an issue, if the exactly same code, on pretty much the same CPU with the same architecture, performs significantly different? How come it crunches through the loop including two instantiations per iteration in less then a second on one CPU and then takes fifteen minutes on another, yet from the same family with nearly identical specs, and even Debug.Log, which can never be more expensive than two instantiations, takes six time longer to go through?

@MeditoDiTerra are you comparing build vs editor play mode? How is it possible you can make your code work in editor but not be able to build application? Mystery. You are being ridiculous, you are arguing instead of posting ANY code that seems to be causing problems. I bet this is problem with loading some resources, but I feel I've already said that and we got no progress since then, so basicaly you are wasting my time right now.
